# How do I add a constraint for a list to not be empty in smithy?

Tags: constraints, traits

How do I add a constraint for a list to not be empty in smithy?
I have a smithy list as below -

```
list CarsList {
    member: Car
}

struct Car {
    @required
    Name: CarName
}

@length(min: 1)
string CarName
```

I want to add a constraint/trait to the list `CarList` to not allow it to be empty.

I tried to add `@required` to `CarName` in `struct Car` and `@length(min: 1)` to `string Carname` as shown above but it did not do any work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `@min` trait for such requirements.

```
list CarsList {
    @min(1)
    member: Car
}

struct Car {
    @required
    Name: CarName
}

@length(min: 1)
string CarName
```

If you create an instance of `CarsList` with no elements, it will be considered invalid. `@min` trait specifies a minimum amount of elements that the list must have, here we have at least `1` is required.

Answer (score 0):

`@min` did not work for me,
but `@length` worked for me.

```
@length(min: 1)
list CarsList {
    member: Car
}

struct Car {
    @required
    Name: CarName
}

@length(min: 1)
string CarName
```

Comment: It seems that you unnecessarily contrast your appreciated solution to the existing answer. Consider [edit] to make this a standalone post. Otherwise consider explicitly contrasting, e.g. "In contrast to the existing answer ( link ), I had to use ... instead of ..., because in my case ..., which you might also encounter and might need to handle."